# Global Array that Function Can Edit in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am working with Excel VBA and am trying to use a global array to keep track of different counts. Different subs and functions are able to access the global array `array_count`, but my goal is to have function `Chart` edit the values in the array. Right now, the function's edits to the array do not carry over to the other subs.

```
' Initialize variables
Private counter As Integer
Private Account As String

Public array_count As Variant

' Iterate over rows, reading Account
Sub RowInsert()

    array_count = Array(-1, -1, -1)

    Debug.Print array_count(0)
    Debug.Print array_count(1)
    Debug.Print array_count(2)

    For counter = 0 To 1

    Account = Worksheets("Journal").Cells(counter + 2, 2)

    Call Record(Account)

    Next counter

    End Sub

    ' Record the transaction in proper T-account 
Sub Record(Account As String)

        Dim target_row As Long

        With Worksheets("Ledger").Range("a1:c20")

            Set Header = .Find(Account)

                Debug.Print Account

            If Header Is Nothing Then

                Debug.Print "Not found."

            End If

            Dim n As Integer
            n = Chart(Account)

            Debug.Print n

            target_row = Header.row + 2 + array_count(n)

            Debug.Print target_row

            Rows(target_row).Insert Shift:=xlDown

            Cells(target_row - 1, 1) = Worksheets("Journal").Cells(counter + 2, 1).Value

                Debug.Print counter

            If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Journal").Cells(counter + 2, 3)) Then

                Cells(target_row - 1, 3) = Worksheets("Journal").Cells(counter + 2, 4).Value

            Else

                Cells(target_row - 1, 2) = Worksheets("Journal").Cells(counter + 2, 3).Value

            End If

        End With

    End Sub

    ' Count the number of entries in each T-account
    Function Chart(Account As String) As Integer

    If Account = "Cash" Then

        array_count(0) = array_count(0) + 1
        Chart = array_count(0)


    ElseIf Account = "Equipment" Then

        array_count(1) = array_count(1) + 1
        Chart = array_count(1)

        Debug.Print array_count(1)


    End If

    End Function
```

Comment: So after the line `n = Chart(Account)`, when it sends you into the next sub, what does `n` become? A value, or nothing? Is the function working at all, or is it setting `Chart = [whatever]`, but then `[whatever]` isn't being recognized in the main sub?

Comment: Oh, I realize that this is simply a logic mistake on my part. I should change the `Chart = array_count(0)` to simply `Chart = 0`, and it works. This seems like not the best design. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why aren't you just passing it around as a parameter? On the same note, why *do you* pass your global variables as parameters?

Comment: There are unqualified references in `Sub Record`.  What `Worksheet` is being edited but by that subroutine?

Comment: Ledger is edited by that Subroutine, though I've noticed that it doesn't work if the worksheet Journal is open when I run it.

Comment: That is because of the unqualified references.  The code will also throw an error if the account isn't found.

Comment: If you can provide a screenshot Worksheets("Ledger"); I'll refactor the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I realize correctly, your issue is that whenever you run RowInsert() you always get the same values of the array_count(0) (I suppose, that is why you have the debug.prints there).

The reason for this is, that on the line:

```
array_count = Array(-1, -1, -1)
```

you are reinitiating the array every time (making it look like -1,-1,-1). Am I right?